# Where to find the max resolution for a touchscreen monitor in Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, rhel6

The application that I'm writing has a thread that is constantly polling a `/dev/input/eventX` location for touch events since the Linux kernel I am running has limited support for touchscreens. Because of this limited support, QT5 does not receive any touch events, and I have to parse the raw event data from the device.

My method works, but I am getting wildly inaccurate X and Y values for the touch points because I need to scale the coordinates according to the resolution of the monitor. For example, if I use the `evtest` utility, I'm able to see that the current max X and Y values for this monitor are (15360, 8640), and the monitor resolution is 1920x1080. This would imply I need to scale both X and Y values by **0.125** to get the correct coordinates.

Since the `evtest` utility is able to show me these max X and Y values, I'm assuming that information can be read somewhere, but I can't find any information on where to get that info. Could someone tell me where I can find the touchscreen's current max coordinate values? Also, if it is not in the same location, where can I get the monitor resolution as well?

Comment: Questioning assumptions: Why are you using QT in the first place?

Comment: @derik Because my company's application is written in QT?

Comment: Do you wanna do via command line?

Comment: @oblivion Preferably not, as I need to be able to get these values via C++, so if there is a file I can read or a Linux header with a function to retrieve these values, that would be preferable.

Comment: Have you looked at the source code to `evtest` to see how it gets the info you want? On the other hand, to me it doesn't look like your linux kernel has limited support for your touch screen if the events are visible through `/dev/input/eventX`. That is *all* the kernel is supposed to do. To have the events be visible through the `QT` api, you first have to make sure `X11` reads from `/dev/input/eventX`. I would recommend against parsing the device file directly. Qt may draw on a different screen or coordinate than where you expect.

Comment: @HAL9000 I'm using Linux kernel 2.6.32-754. My understanding was that support for touchscreens is extremely minimal in this version and Xorg interfaces do not respond to the touch events, and Qt5 has never raised a touch event even after writing event handlers for them and enabling touch events for the window.

Comment: @HAL9000 Also, how would I get X11 to read from that event location? The xorg.conf file? I have yet to be able to figure out how to configure anything in that file properly.

Comment: 2.6.32 is old as dirt. Is your X server just as old? Configuration of X depends on the version. Newer versions on modern distributions tend to be plug-and-play. I would recommend that you upgrade.

Comment: @HAL9000 As I said, it's my company's tech stack, not mine. Upgrading is not an option because it would require rewriting a massive amount of code. I was able to get a simple pinch-zoom operation working using my method, but I need to be able to touch Qt widgets, so I need accurate touch coordinates.

Comment: "the evtest utility is able to show me these max X and Y values" - So, read its source code already, to see how it does that..

Comment: If you can't upgrade, then at least fix `xorg.conf` so you access touch through X and QT. There are to many "fun" ways to screw up when mapping raw events to qt-widgets. Like remote desktops, ui-themes, etc... And when you write to "wonky" interfaces, your users and system administrators are *really* going to love you. Do you really want to receive a phone call during holiday because somebody bought a new touchscreen, configured the OS to work with said screen, and your program was the only thing that stopped working?  And what when management finally decides to upgrade their software stack?

Comment: @HAL9000 The entire machine, and all the software on it, is from us. We provide the touchscreen. It's a canonical solution for now, but I'll be working towards getting something better working if it's possible. I'm not ignoring your comments, but all evidence I've seen in my research shows that this version of Linux won't natively be able to do what you're suggesting, and upgrading is not a possibility at the moment, so this is my only option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find the source code for the `evtest` utility that I mentioned and was able to find the max X and Y values of the touchscreen by using the following code snippet:

```cpp
const char * filename = "/dev/input/event15";
char * absval[6] = { "Value", "Min", "Max", "Fuzz", "Flat", "Resolution" };
int fd = open(filename, O_RDONLY);
if((fd < 0) && (errno == EACCES) && (getuid() != 0)) {
    cout << "Could not open device file. Try running as root." << endl;
}

int absX[6] = {};
int absY[6] = {};

ioctl(fd, EVIOCGABS(ABS_MT_POSITION_X), absX);
ioctl(fd, EVIOCGABS(ABS_MT_POSITION_Y), absY);

cout << "ABS_MT_POSITION_X Properties" << endl;
for(int x = 0; x < 6; x++) {
    if((x < 3) || absX[x]) {
        cout << absval[x] << ": " << absX[x] << endl;
    }
}

cout << "ABS_MT_POSITION_Y Properties" << endl;
for(int y = 0; y < 6; y++) {
    if((y < 3) || absX[y]) {
        cout << absval[y] << ": " << absY[y] << endl;
    }
}

SCALE_X = (1920.0f / absX[2]);
SCALE_Y = (1080.0f / absY[2]);

close(fd);
```

This got me the correct scaling amount.

Is there a way to do this using C++ libraries? Or is there no C++ equivalent to ioctl()?

Comment: ioctl is inherently OS specific. The C++ standard doesn't deal with this. If you prefer a non-standard C++ wrapper around ioctl over bare unwrapped ioctl, just write one. BTW if you want to ask a question, hit the "Ask a question" button.

Comment: @n.m. Alright. It was still an answer, I just figured someone could answer that tangential question in the comments because it wasn't super important.